# JSON encode non primitive types in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, encode

Helo I would like to encode non standard types such as `sims_float3x3` and `[vector_float3]`. What is the recommended way to this?

I tried to use `Struct` like so,

```
struct Example: Codable {
    var test_var1:simd_float3x3
    var test_var2:[vector_float3]
}
```

I get the error, `does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

I also tried,

```
let data = try encoder.encode(test_var1)
```

I get the error - `Argument type 'simd_float3x3' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'`

I currently can do like so,

```
let data_col1 = try encoder.encode(test_var1.columns.0) // simd_float3
let data_col2 = try encoder.encode(test_var1.columns.1) // simd_float3
let data_col3 = try encoder.encode(test_var1.columns.2) // simd_float3
```

But is there any way to do this more elegantly / efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same technique as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48494133/2303865) for the outer array:

```
import SceneKit

extension simd_float3x3: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try self.init(container.decode([float3].self))
    }
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode([columns.0, columns.1, columns.2])
     }
 }
```

---

**Playground testing**

```
let simdFloat = simd_float3x3(float3(0, 1, 2), float3(3,4, 5), float3(6, 7, 8))
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(simdFloat)
    let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(simd_float3x3.self, from: data)
    print(decodedObject)  // simd_float3x3([[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]])

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```